# not able to set empty string in log4net NullText property via application/web.config

Tags: configuration, .net-4.5, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am trying to set following in my web services and windows services application

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.NullText" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

But got (null) against the property whom text we have provided.
If i do add following line

```
log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NullText = string.Empty;
```

in my application start call then it does work.But i wanted to control it via configuration only as i have number of components.

I am using .net 4.5.2  and log4net version 2.0.8

Comment: If you set the value to a string like "test", does it work? (I'm not suggesting you use that in your logs, just as a test to see if log4net is picking up the value)

Comment: Yes it does come. i have set value="Test" and it appears in log

Comment: @staurtd. Any suggestion?

Comment: An empty string looks to still be unsupported through config. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-55?focusedCommentId=12707985&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12707985

Answer (score 0):

Working for me. I assume you didn't set the app.config to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer" so the changes didn't take place.